# Output name of named pattern in sed or grep

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

I'm looking for a solution to output the name of named pattern in regular expression

Regex - can contain **n** patterns, each named *id**n***, no duplicates:

```
(?P<id1>aba)|(?P<id2>cde)|(?P<id3>esa)|(?P<id4>fav)
```

input-file:

```
aba
cec
fav
gex
hur
```

output (any of the following):

```
id1
id4

id1;id4

1
4

1;4
```

Is there any way to do it with sed or grep on a linux os. The input file is a text file 200-500MB.
I know that PHP outputs pattern names in output array, but I'd prefer not to use it.

Any other solution is also welcome, but it should use basic linux commands.

Comment: Neither `sed` nor `grep` support the Perl regex extension you are trying to use. Is there a reason you don't use Perl for this? (Points for refusing to use PHP though.)

Comment: `grep -Po` works with that regex, but it outputs matched strings

Comment: Yeah, `grep -P` supports Perl *patterns* but does not as such expose additional features so you could do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple Perl script which does what you ask.

```
perl -nle 'if (m/(?P<id1>aba)|(?P<id2>cde)|(?P<id3>esa)|(?P<id4>fav)/) {
    for my $pat (keys %+) { print $pat } }' filename
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm marking it as an answer, although it takes perl 3 seconds to search in a 300 MB file, while it takes only 1 second with grep ;)